# Getting 404 Not Found in Laravel AJAX Request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

In my Laravel Projects, I want to pass data from blade to my controller using Ajax.

But I am getting error

> 404 | Not Found

**ajax**

```
var pi_id = $(this).attr('href');    
$.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('purchase-invoice-detail') }}",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            'id': pi_id
        },
        success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed                
                alert('ok'); 
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert('Error'+response);
        }
    });
```

**route**

```
Route::get('purchase-invoice-detail/{id}', 'PurchaseController@purchase_invoice_detail')->middleware('auth');
```

**controller**

```
public function purchase_invoice_detail($id)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Can't find the problem.

Anybody Help Please ?

Comment: Try this `"{{ url('purchase-invoice-detail') }}"  + '/' + pi_id ` as the url

Comment: @SahandMoghadam....same result....`404 Not Found`

Comment: So check the network tab on Chrome DevTools and post the Request Url.

Comment: Can you share html ? how you calling ajax i.e. click ?

Comment: @SahandMoghadam....it's done now.... Yours one is correct....I was missing double quoted comma...now it's ok....
But what is the problem og passing data through Ajax `data` object?

Comment: @ArafatRahman Because you are requiring id as a query parameter in route not in body.

Comment: @SahandMoghadam....please give your code as an answer....I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
"{{ url('purchase-invoice-detail') }}"  + '/' + pi_id
```